# 64bit int differences between .NET and javascript

Tags: javascript, .net

I'm passing a long int from C# (DateTime.Now().Ticks) to a web page then trying to pass it back for the sake of concurrency.

634290758865783994 becomes 
634290758865783900

Why is this? I thought both the System.Long and Javascript Number were 64 bit integers.

Comment: Have you tested to see exactly where the conversion is taking place?

Comment: I know little about these things, so I won't dare to attempt an answer. But were I to venture a guess, I'd say maybe it has something to do with the number starting as a 64-bit unsigned integer, and being converted to a 64-bit signed float. I don't think javascript actually has integers. I'll let the smart people take over for the real answer.

Comment: You might end up having to pass it as a string, depends on what you're using it on the Javascript side for though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ECMAScript (the formal name for javascript) stores numbers as [IEEE-754 double precision floating-points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

These can only represent the values up to 2^53 using the significant bits, and everything above this will be an approximation.

Comment: The 2nd part of your answer is not quite correct. The double-precision floating-point format allows for more than 2^53 values. I guess what you meant to say is that the mantissa (fraction part) of a "double" is only 52 bits wide and therefore, only a limited number of significant digits can be represented.

Comment: I'm not an expert on binary representation of large numbers so you might very well be right. I'll see if I can refrase it :)